# How to select different columns sum in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the sum of different cites according to time column in my database. The required result will be as like below image.

Please have a look at the image.

[image]

AND finally I want to print the above data in my web page using PHP.

Comment: `SUM()`, `GROUP BY` is your friends.

Comment: did not understand. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you write, may be something like:

```
SELECT city, sum(amount) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE MONTH(date_column)=12 
GROUP BY city;
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use a combination of `SUM(CASE...)` and `GROUP BY` clause. Something like this

```
SELECT
   city,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate)=1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as january,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate)=2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as february,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate)=3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as march
FROM orders
GROUP BY city
```

I'm assuming the table name is `ORDERS` and using the column `orderDate` to identify the mounth.

Good luck, bro.

Comment: Bro How to print this in PHP. I want to store city and month in php variable and want to print

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish that. I'd recommend you to use PHP PDO interface and store the results as a list of arrays or object. Please chekout this tutorial 

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Brother I am still unable to store into variable and print the data using php. the query runs perfect in mysql query window box but I want the same result in my web browser using PHP. Please how to do this.

Comment: @SaleemJafar, this is not too simple. There are many tutorials about this. I think it's a good point to start. Try this one, for exemple http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_select_php.htm